# How does the command-line option "W1" differ from "W0"?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

From within a Ruby script, verbosity can be tested with the value of the `$VERBOSE` global variable, which can have three states:

```
nil in case verbosity level was “0” (silence)
false for level “1” (medium); this is the default
true for level “2” (verbose); this is verbose mode.
```

I started to play with my code to understand the difference between them:

```
@ubuntu:~$ ruby -W0 -e 'a=10;a=10;@foo'
@ubuntu:~$ ruby -W1 -e 'a=10;a=10;@foo'
@ubuntu:~$ ruby -W2 -e 'a=10;a=10;@foo'
-e:1: warning: possibly useless use of a variable in void context
-e:1: warning: instance variable @foo not initialized
@ubuntu:~$
```

But really could not understand what the difference between `W1` and `W0`. Could anyone help me to understand the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the real difference, you have to print some text on the $STDERR. I've made the following change on your example:

```
ruby -W0 -e 'a=10;a=10;@foo;warn "hello"'
```

Note that running the code with the `W0` flag, nothing will appear in the terminal when you execute. Now, if you run with the `W1`, you will see the "error" message generated by the `Kernel#warn`:

```
ruby -W1 -e 'a=10;a=10;@foo;warn "hello"'
```

And finally, the `W2` will show the error and the warnings generated by the interpreter.

Comment: Humm, understood that, `W0` suppress everything but `w1` can do all except `warn`. Now my quick question is how the message from `warn` differs from the other warnings produced by code?

Comment: @user2060534 The `Kernel#warn` prints the message on the STDERR. While the "normal" warns are printed on the STDOUT. This helps?